# Alphabet Encryption

Tags: encryption

Right now I cant even compile this program. Im trying to write a program that takes a inputted string and then encrypts the letters by swapping them out with another letter predetermined in a array and then shows you again the original text. any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {
    private char [] alphabet = new char [25];
    private char [] crypt = new char [25];
    String oldMessage;


    public Array()
    {    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnoptqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); 
     char[] crypt = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm|".toCharArray();

    }        

    public static void run(){ 

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a message that you would like to encrypt\n");
        oldMessage = scan.nextLine();

        String newMessage = "";
        for (int i=0; i<oldMessage.length(); ++i) {
            int index = alphabet.indexOf(old.charAt(i));
            if (index == -1)
                newMessage +="?";
            else 
                newMessage += crypt.charAt(index);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {Array myApplication = new Array(); myApplication.run();}
```

Comment: Define "can't even compile."  Is there an error?  Do you not have a Java compiler?  Is the computer turned off?  Please be specific.

Comment: I meant that it compiles but has no output when it runs.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this code compiles, since I can manually see things which would definitely cause compilation errors.  You have unterminated code blocks, you're referencing instance members from static members, etc.  If this code compiles, your compiler is broken.  If this code doesn't compile, your question is unanswerable.  If this isn't the code you're actually using, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: the errors im having are 1. non-static variable oldMessage cannot be referenced from a static context That is the main error from old message scan line all the way down until the end and the i get illegal start of expression. Im sorry Im new at this, just trying to get some help hopefully i provided enough information

Answer (score 1):

First off, when encountering errors, it's always best to include the error in your question--often it will point you right to the source of the error. What does your compiler say when the build fails?

Next, I'm on my phone right now and can't verify that I've found all the problems, but remember that strings in Java are immutable, meaning that they can't be changed after creation. This means that you can't append to them in the way you're doing. Try using the StringBuilder class to accomplish what you're looking for here, or filling a new array as you go and converting to String at the end.

Also, it looks like you're missing two end braces (the for loop and the run method).

Comment: the errors im having are 1. non-static variable oldMessage cannot be referenced from a static context That is the main error from old message scan line all the way down until the end and the i get illegal start of expression. Im sorry Im new at this, just trying to get some help hopefully i provided enough information

Comment: make those variables static

Comment: Better to just make the run method non-static; the way your class I'd built there's almost no reason for anything to be static.

Answer (score 0):

From static method `run()` you are referring to non-static variables like `alphabet, crypt, oldMessage`.
This is first that comes into mind